# How to find dublicate in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U04o.png)

- This method will check to see if number 'n'

  - is in the array of integers stored in the method more than once
  - 
  - It returns true if it is duplicated in the array and false
  - if not

  */

My code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < myYears.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myYears.length; j++) {
                      // got the duplicate element
                 System.out.println("Got dublicate");
                 return true;     
        }
    }
    return false;
```

However all i get is "got Dublicate" no matter the input.

Edit 1

```
package main;
```

public class Array1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    findMoreThanOneInArray(1231);      // test will return true

}  // end main

/*

 * This method will check to see if number 'n'

 * is in the array of integers stored in the method more than once

 * 

 * It returns true if it is duplicated in the array and false

 * if not

 */

private static boolean findMoreThanOneInArray(int n) {

    boolean result = false;     // default the search to false

    int[] myYears = { 2176, 2311, 2472, 2131, 2046, 2209, 2473, 2364, 2116, 2462, 2405, 2032, 2226, 2223, 2065, 2336, 2372, 2084, 2000, 2074, 2263, 2092, 2485, 2229, 2222, 2369, 2130, 2381, 2487, 2271, 2432, 2011, 2264, 2328, 2251, 2002, 2036, 2410, 2166, 2022, 2064, 2168, 2122, 2409, 2100, 2276, 2361, 2042, 2387, 2211, 2479, 2327, 2044, 2319, 2308, 2265, 2368, 2021, 2325, 2395, 2256, 2086, 2449, 2171, 2098, 2117, 2468, 2338, 2214, 2314, 2204, 2073, 2045, 2295, 2020, 2447, 2233, 2060, 2094, 2383, 2457, 2260, 2224, 2105, 2261, 2405, 2472, 2477, 2253, 2175, 2107, 2441, 2379, 2027, 2386, 2090, 2496, 2280, 2285, 2117 };


    /*

     * you code goes here

     * return true if n is duplicated in the array, false otherwise

     */
    for (int i = 0; i < myYears.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1 ; j < myYears.length; j++) {
            if (myYears[i] == myYears[j]) {
                 System.out.println("Got dublicate");
                 return true;
             }
        }
    }
    return false;
     

} // end of method
```

} // end class

Edit 2

```
for (int i = 0; i < myYears.length; i++) {
        
            if (myYears[i] == n) {
                 System.out.println("Got dublicate");
                 return true;
             }
    }
   System.out.println("false");
    return false;
```

The Edit 2 passed all tests but one, for value of n = 2222; can anyone suggest why ?

[Passed all tests but one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw41V.png)

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs (`https://ericlippert.com/`)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) --- You do not access the array `myYear` at all; variables `i` and `j` represent the *indices*, not the values in the array. We can access the elements in the array at index `i` with `myYears[i]`. I recommend reading a tutorial on arrays, e.g. [this one from [`oracle.com`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Where's the part where you don't print "Got dublicate"?

Comment: You're not actually doing anything. Your code simply loops through all the pairs of numbers in the array (even any number paired with itself, that's going to be a problem), but you're not doing anything then. You're looking for some kind of comparison, `if (myYears[i] == myYears[j)) { ... }` condition. And then there are some more clever solutions, but for those you need some algorithmization, your solution will work with some tinkering.

Comment: @PetrJaneček can you check edit 2 please

Comment: Your 2nd edit is just checking for a single occurence in the array. not a duplicate. There is only one 2222 in the array.

Comment: @greg-449 How would I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are searching for...

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < myYears.length; i++) {    
    if (myYears[i] == n) {
        count++;
    }
}
        
if (count >= 2) {
    System.out.println("true");
    return true; 
}

System.out.println("false");
return false;
```

This code basically increments the variable `count` every time by 1 if the given value is found in the array. After the for loop, we check if the variable `count` is greater or equal to the value `2` (because we need to know if the given number `n` is appearing more than once)